# open folder using path with space in name from my javascript framework... syntax issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open a network folder by using the following in my extjs javascript project.

```
window.open("http://127.0.0.1:8887/a/b/");
```

the above works fine but when there is a space in the path it no longer works

```
window.open("http://127.0.0.1:8887/a/b c/");
```

the above does not work.  anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", doStuff);

function doStuff(){
    let button = document.getElementById("navButton");
    console.log(button);
    button.onclick = () => {

        var url="http://localhost:3000/a/ c/index.html";
        url = encodeURI(url);
        console.log(url);
        window.open(url, "_new");
    };
}
```

```html
<button id="navButton">Click Me</button>
```

I think you need to encode the URL first.

```js
let url = "http://127.0.0.1/a/d/ c/";
let encoded = encodeURI(url);

console.log(encoded);

//window.open(encoded);
```

Comment: I tried and not working.  I think it is because I don't understand the path.  this works window.open("http://127.0.0.1:8887/a/b/"); but the above does not work.  here is the weird part... the output is writing to the console... if I click on that path in the console output, it opens successfully.  BUT when the my code hits window.open(encoded), nothing happens at all.  any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I set up a sample project in VSCode on a Mac, using Lite-Server loading into Chrome. See the code below, it worked just fine. Opening the page into a new window.